# Combining java.util.Dates to create a date-time

Tags: java, datetime

I have current have two UI components used to specify a date and a time.  Both components return `java.util.Date` instances representing the calendar date and time respectively.  My question is:

What is the best way to combine these values to create a `java.util.Date` instance representing the date and time?  **I would like to avoid dependencies on Joda or other 3rd party libraries.**

My current solution looks like this (but is there a better way?):

```
Date date = ... // Calendar date
Date time = ... // Time

Calendar calendarA = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarA.setTime(date);

Calendar calendarB = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarB.setTime(time);

calendarA.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendarB.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
calendarA.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendarB.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
calendarA.set(Calendar.SECOND, calendarB.get(Calendar.SECOND));
calendarA.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, calendarB.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

Date result = calendarA.getTime();
```

Comment: That's as good as you'll get without using a proper API.

Comment: I think this is *why* third-party date/time libraries exist :-(

Comment: Hmmm ... Thanks - That's what I suspected.

Comment: Date(int, int, int, int, int, int) is deprecated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public Date dateTime(Date date, Date time) {
    return new Date(
                     date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), 
                     time.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds()
                   );
}
```

you can corvert this deprecated code to Calendar obtaining your solution.

Then my answer is: *no, you cannot do better without using joda*

**NB**

jodatime soon will be standardized with [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)

Comment: although I agree that this should not be used, but even if someone did, maybe you should fix it for them. `date.getDay()` returns the day in week. Here you will need `day.getDate()`

Comment: I agree with @medopal, this solution should not be used over the OPs solution.

Comment: Please mark in bold **this is deprecated code: do not use it**

Answer (score 4):

I think you're approach is the best you're likely to get without using Joda time. A solution using SimpleDateFormats might use fewer lines, but is not really giving you any benefit.

Comment: Not clear to me what in this answer is worthy of a downvote. Would anyone care to explain?

Comment: -1: The question clearly states that the dependency of Joda time isn't desired. Therefore it's not an answer to the question. If the author finds it worth mentioning, it belongs to a comment IMHO - not a fully-fledged answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Using Calendar

```
public Date dateTime(Date date, Date time) {

    Calendar aDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    aDate.setTime(date);

    Calendar aTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    aTime.setTime(time);

    Calendar aDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    aDateTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, aDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    aDateTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, aDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    aDateTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, aDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    aDateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, aTime.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    aDateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, aTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    aDateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, aTime.get(Calendar.SECOND));

    return aDateTime.getTime();
}
```