# Combining two Date instance to create date-time using Joda

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have two `java.util.Date` instances which is contain date value and time value. now I want to combine these values to create single `java.util.Date` instance representing the date and time.

here some example to make clear what I'd want :

```
      Date date = 2015-06-01;
      Date time = 22:30;
```

combine into :

```
     Date dateTime = 2015-06-01 22:30;
```

I do some search and I found this question 
[Combining java.util.Dates to create a date-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260112/combining-java-util-dates-to-create-a-date-time)
which is similar with my current issue. But the chosen answer on that question is deprecated.

Comment: Not possible. You cannot have a java.util.Date object that is only a date or only a time-of-day. A j.u.Date always has both. It is actually is a count of milliseconds since 1970 in UTC time zone, so there actually is not a separation of date and te-of-day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it without JODA, by using Calendar

However, as you asked about JODA, here is the way to do in JODA:

```
// you want the date part from it
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse("2013-01-02 03:04:05");

// you want to time part from it
Date t = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse("2014-02-03 04:05:06");


LocalDate datePart = new LocalDate(d);
LocalTime timePart = new LocalTime(t);
LocalDateTime dateTime = datePart.toLocalDateTime(timePart);
Date result = dateTime.toDate();

// Or shrink the above 4 lines into one, as follow
// Date result = new LocalDate(d).toLocalDateTime(new LocalTime(t)).toDate();

System.out.println("result " + result);
// print out result Wed Jan 02 04:05:06 CST 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Calendar instead?

In particular, [set(int year,
                      int month,
                      int date,
                      int hourOfDay,
                      int minute)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) and
if you want a Date, use [getTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) ?

or convert the Date object to a Calendar object using the `setTime(Date ..`) function from the Calendar class, extract the values (day, hours, minute) using functions from the Calendar class?