# Unexpected result when summing java Dates

Tags: java, datetime

I get an unexpected result when summing java Date objects using their method java.util.Date.getTime().

Here's the sample code:

```
System.out.println(d1.toString()); 
System.out.println(d2.toString());
System.out.println(new Date(d1.getTime() + d2.getTime()));
```

Here is the output:

```
Mon Mar 20 00:00:00 CET 2017
Thu Jan 01 10:44:00 CET 1970
Mon Mar 20 09:44:00 CET 2017
```

I would expect to have *Mon Mar 20 10:44:00 CET 2017* instead of *Mon Mar 20 09:44:00 CET 2017*.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this is related to winter/summer time or problem with time zone. I suggest you use JodaTime as util for manipulating dates

Comment: I tried your code [in an online compiler (TIO)](https://tio.run/##dU/LasMwELz7Kxaf5BYZyQ2E2PTWllwMBfdWelAtNZVrWcZa50HJt7tSfGhCiFhYNDszu9OIraCN/JkmbXo7IDQeSEfUbXpXROcYqj0GrG6Fc1AK3f1GAP342eoaHAr0bWu1BONHpMJBd5v3DxAJ4Pdgdw5exeDU875WPWp7EgNUfkOrngSqFzsYgfA1t0fo1O5qSuKDf7QsqZSwXufG5M7FSXGyCjSQ3Etnj7QP@0icMb6k7IFmDBjLT3Upya4kfLVklHFfwFm@WJxJqoNDZVI7erJPiG1HJE/RznlJkhRwk5dd8G7RQvBwWPDdKHzTRpEE7v2d/99ZfoyO0/QH) and I indeed got `Mon Mar 20 10:44:00 UTC 2017` as result. Are you sure both use the same time-type (CET, UTC, summer/winter, etc.)?

Comment: agree with @isnot2bad, it is nonsense

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. What is the expected result of Mon Mar 20 00:00:00 CET 2017 + Thu Jan 01 10:44:00 CET 1970??

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` at all, the class is long outdated. Instead use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). To add an amount of time to a date-time, use for example `ZonedDateTime` and its `plus` method, for example pass a `Duration` object containing the amount to add. `Instant`, `LocalDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime` have similar `plus` methods. And they work as expected with very little room for surprises like the one you got.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260112/combining-java-util-dates-to-create-a-date-time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us ignore the fact that it is completely nonsense to sum up dates (a date is a point on the timeline - addition is simply not defined for dates - you can add a duration to a date or sum up two durations, but never two dates).

The problem is that your dates are in the central european time zone (CET), so you're one hour ahead of time.

`d1.getTime()` returns the milliseconds since 1st of january 1970 **GMT**, so if you create a new `Date` object for this date (1/jan/1970) in your time zone (CET I suppose), `getTime()` will return -3600000 due to the time zone shift.

*Additonal Info*

If you really want to add a duration to a point in time, consider using the new [Java Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). It has several types to represent dates, times, dates+times and durations. E.g.:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
Duration fiveDays = Duration.ofDays(5);
Period oneYearTwoMonthsThreeDays = Period.of(1, 2, 3);

System.out.println(now);
System.out.println(now.plus(fiveDays));
System.out.println(now.plus(oneYearTwoMonthsThreeDays));
```

Comment: Generally speaking I agree it does not make much sense, but I get date and time from two distinct oracle DATE columns hence i need to sum them.

Comment: So I assume the second date is not a real date, but a duration?

Comment: And how do you retrieve it from the database? As String, as long (in millis) or as java.sql.Date?

Comment: Basically by default the proprietary framework used in my company looks at the ResultSet metadata and infers the type of each field. Then builds an HashMap with every field selected by the query. Values contained in date columns are converted in java.util.Date. In this case, (honestly I don't know why) time and date are stored in two different DB columns by a web service businness logic. The column containing the time information has january 1st 1970 as date.

Comment: Your use of `LocalDateTime` here is the wrong class. That class lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it cannot represent a specific moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. Replace with either `Instant` (always in UTC) or `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: It represents a specific moment in my local time zone, which might be sufficient if the date/time stored in the database has no time zone information attached. In this case inferring/guessing additional time zone info is useless and maybe even dangerous IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, your time zone is Europe/Rome (or some other Central European time zone, you can easily substitute below if needed). You get two `java.util.Date` instances from your company’s framework. They are really both misused in that one denotes the date and has time-of-day 00:00:00 in your time zone, the other has date Jan 1, 1970 and the time of day that you need, still in your time zone. You need to combine the date from the former with the time of day of the latter. Particularly because of the latter you need to take time zone into account when combining the two.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome");

    LocalTime timeOfDay = d2.toInstant().atZone(zone).toLocalTime();
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = d1.toInstant().atZone(zone).with(timeOfDay);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

This prints:

> 2017-03-20T10:44+01:00[Europe/Rome]

The time is 10:44 as you had expected, `+01:00` is the offset from UTC.

If you do need a `java.util.Date` object, for example for a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change just now (and only in this case), convert like this:

```
    Date asOldfashionedDate = Date.from(dateTime.toInstant());
    System.out.println(asOldfashionedDate);
```

Output:

> Mon Mar 20 10:44:00 CET 2017

### Check the assumptions

You should want to validate the assumptions I made above so you will catch if they don’t hold. In the following version of the same code I do that.

```
    ZonedDateTime dateZdt = d1.toInstant().atZone(zone);
    if (! dateZdt.equals(dateZdt.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(zone))) {
        System.out.println("Date was not at start of day: " + d1);
    }
    ZonedDateTime timeZdt = d2.toInstant().atZone(zone);
    if (! timeZdt.toLocalDate().equals(LocalDate.EPOCH)) {
        System.out.println("Time of day was not on January 1, 1970: " + d2);
    }
    LocalTime timeOfDay = timeZdt.toLocalTime();
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = dateZdt.with(timeOfDay);
```

The result is the same as before, only we’re now more confident that it is also correct.

### What went wrong in your code?

`d1` correctly denotes the date at time 00:00 in your time zone. `d2` denotes the time of day in your time zone. Now *if* `d2.getTime()` had given you the number of millisseconds since midnight in your time zone, your trick wold have worked. But it doesn’t. The milliseconds you get are counted from 00:00 in UTC, where your time zone had an offset from UTC of 1 hour in the winter of 1970. This is what causes your result to be wrong by 1 hour.

### Link

[The Java™ Tutorials: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining to use `java.time` including the classes I used: `ZoneId`,  `LocalTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, `LocalDate` and more.

Answer (score 1):

The epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, while CET gets UTC + 1. This is the procedure:

```
input: 2017-03-20 00:00:00 CET —--> 2017-03-19 23:00:00 UTC
input: 1970-01-01 10:44:00 CET —--> 1970-01-01 09:44:00 UTC

// change inputs to the long millis to epoch and sum them
2017-03-19 23:00:00 UTC + 1970-01-01 09:44:00 UTC = 2017-03-20 08:44:00 UTC

output: 2017-03-20 08:44:00 UTC —--> 2017-03-20 09:44:00 CET
```